# How can I code a function within a function?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to nest functions within a main function in JavaScript? I've been playing around with some code, and I can't get my function to display anything to the screen.

```
function main() {
    var crew;
    var crewMemberWeight = 113;
    var winterWeight = 2.8;
    var winter = false;
    var capacity = 24000;
    var cargo = [1000, 5500, 2000, 3500, 4000, 7000];

    function cargoWeight(cargo) {
        total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < cargo.length; i++) {
            total += cargo[i];
        }
        document.write("Cargo weight: " + total);
        return total;
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: You're not calling `cargoWeight` anywhere.

Comment: Oh, alright. I was thinking that if I called my main function below, the functions within it may be called as well.

Comment: Even if that was the case, your function takes an argument of 'load' which isn't defined anywhere so it would fail.

Comment: Why can't you put `cargoWeight(load)` outside the `main()` and call it like you would any other function.  IE  `cargoWeight(2000);`

Comment: Where would you have gotten the idea that merely declaring a function would somehow magically execute it, in any context, inside another function or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function main() {
    var crew;
    var crewMemberWeight = 113;
    var winterWeight = 2.8;
    var winter = false;
    var capacity = 24000;
    var cargo = [1000, 5500, 2000, 3500, 4000, 7000];

    function cargoWeight(cargo) {
        total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < cargo.length; i++) {
            total += cargo[i];
        }
        document.write("Cargo weight: " + total);
        return total;
    }

    // you have to call the function and pass in cargo. Not just define it
    cargoWeight(cargo)
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call this internal function inside main(). I would do: cargoWeight(cargo); before last bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the cargoWeight function at the end.  Looking at your code it looks like you want to pass the cargo variable in.

```
function main() {
var crew;
var crewMemberWeight = 113;
var winterWeight = 2.8;
var winter = false;
var capacity = 24000;
var cargo = [1000, 5500, 2000, 3500, 4000, 7000];

function cargoWeight(load) {
    total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < load.length; i++) {
        total += load[i];
    }
    document.write("Cargo weight: " + total);
    return total;
}
cargoWeight(cargo);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define functions within functions in javascript. However, when you do so, that nested function can only be called from inside the parent function. So, if you wrote another separate function, you wouldn't be able to call `cargoWeight()` from that other function.

```
function main() {
    var crew;
    var crewMemberWeight = 113;
    var winterWeight = 2.8;
    var winter = false;
    var capacity = 24000;
    var cargo = [1000, 5500, 2000, 3500, 4000, 7000];

    function cargoWeight(load) {
        total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < load.length; i++) {
            total += load[i];
        }
        document.write("Cargo weight: " + total);
        return total;
    }
}

main();

function other(){
    cargoWeight(400)  // can't call this method here
}
```

There are a lot of applications for this which would require a lengthy post to explain, but looking into javascript objects and closures would be a good place to start in order to understand why and how javascript works this way.

Answer (score 0):

first off you need to call 'cargoWeight(load)' you also need to define 'load' that is going to be pulled into the function.

What i think your intent was to add up the 'cargo' array?
see linked fiddle:

www.jsfiddle.net/natLuuy6

Answer (score -1):

This is late to the party, but may be interesting to a "JavaScript beginner".

```
function main()
{
    var crew;
    var crewMemberWeight = 113;
    var winterWeight = 2.8;
    var winter = false;
    var capacity = 24000;
    var cargo = [1000, 5500, 2000, 3500, 4000, 7000];

    function cargoWeight(cargoValues) {
        return cargoValues.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }

    document.write("Cargo weight: ", cargoWeight(cargo));
}

main();
```